# Why doesn't my observable in Angular work as expected?

Tags: angular

I have the following observable, which I DO subscribe to. Yet it does not fire on page load. Can you please help. I get no console errors, by the way

```
  maxBackDateTrigger$ = new Subject<void>();
  isGettingMaxBackDate$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  setMaxBackDate$ = this.maxBackDateTrigger$.pipe(
    tap(() => this.$spService.clientProfile$),
    withLatestFrom(this.$spService.clientProfile$),
    map(([trigger, client]) => {
      this.maxBackdate = client.caseStart;
    })
  );
```

UPDATE: I changed it to the following and it still doesn't work.

```
// this is in ngOnInit
  this.getBackDate$.subscribe();

...

  getSelectedClient$ = new BehaviorSubject<ClientProfile>(null);

  getBackDate$ = this.getSelectedClient$.pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.$spService.clientProfile$),
    tap(([client]) => {
      alert(client.caseStart)
      this.maxBackdate = client.caseStart;
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

[Subject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject)'s do not have a starting value. So when you do `maxBackDateTrigger$ = new Subject<void>();` it would not yeild on load (as designed)

The fix is to change it to a [BehaviorSubject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) as:

> A variant of Subject that requires an initial value and emits its current value whenever it is subscribed to.

changing it to the following should get you going:

```
maxBackDateTrigger$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(null);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't got it working. I made changes though, I you could have a look.

Comment: if you could build a minimum reproducible error in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy) I might help you further

Comment: Thanks so much. I found a simple solution to my problem that didn't even involve RxJs. I do appreciate your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Void subjects have nothing to emit. So unlike value subjects that emit the current value they have once they are subscribed to, void subjects just don't emit anything and hence your trigger doesn't take place.

So because you have a void subject, you would need to explicitly call `next` on page load to fire the subject. That is, after setMaxBackDate$, (or preferably in ngOnInit),

```js
maxBackDateTrigger$.next();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't got it working. I made changes though, I you could have a look.